# Where does EE define "Total Members?"

Tags: members

I just did an import of members into the EE database, populating exp_members, exp_member_data, and exp_member_data_field_* tables. Seems intuitive and worked.

But on the CP homepage, those members aren't being counted in the "Total Members" label.

Anyone know where this value is pulled from? Not the most important thing in the world, but it would be more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you must go to Developer > Utilities > Statistics and sync the "Members" row.